# create font-awesome icon dynamically based on user input angular @fortawesome project

Tags: angular, font-awesome

In my angular 6 application, there is below package I installed fort-awesome.

```
devDependencies: {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.1.0",
}
dependencies: {
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
}
```

and I am using

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faIcon"></fa-icon> 
 & faIcon is defined at component level when I want to import it as static.
```

Now I have input wherein the user types faEye for example and I want to generate an icon. that is not being generated.

```
<input type="text" size="40"  [(ngModel)]="user.iconClass"/>
<fa-icon [icon]="user.iconClass" class="custom-topic-icons" *ngIf="user.iconClass"></fa-icon>
```

but it gives me error saying that icons fas-prefix not exist.

Comment: Where did you have imported the FA modules?

Comment: in app module fiel

Comment: Please, add you `app.module.ts` file to your question.